# How to achieve Flutter Checkbox Stepper?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to achieve the following layout

[image]

I tried using Stepper but it didn't really solved my issue so I tried using vanilla dart code itself

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Checkbox(value: true, onChanged: (value) {}),
              Text("Complaint Received"),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 20,
            ),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              width: 2,
              height: 80,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Checkbox(value: true, onChanged: (value) {}),
              Text("Complaint Received"),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            width: 2,
            height: 10,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Checkbox(value: true, onChanged: (value) {}),
              Text("Complaint Received"),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            width: 2,
            height: 10,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Checkbox(value: true, onChanged: (value) {}),
              Text("Complaint Received"),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            width: 2,
            height: 10,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Following is the ui which I achieved

[image]

I don't understand why there is padding between the first two row and the container

Comment: I wrote a quick app to solve this, will post here in a minute...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Flutter, Checkboxes are not pure widgets like the `StatelessWidget` that we are used to.

`Checkbox` draws its bounds, a box with rounded edges, and the 'check' mark itself through `RenderObject`'s `paint` method, sort of like HTML5 Canvas (if you are familiar).

This fact makes it hard to customize Flutter checkboxes, even changing such trivial stuff like the padding around it.

---

My solution does not solve your problem in the way you tried to, but it does provide a great view just like the one you wanted to achieve.

```dart
final double barsHeight = 40.0;
final double barsWidth = 3.0;
final Color inactiveBarColor = Colors.grey;
final Color activeBarColor = Colors.blue;

Map<String, bool> steps = {
  "Complaint Received": true,
  "Engineer Assigned": true,
  "Engineer On the way": false,
  "Complaint Done": false,
};

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  double rowPadding = (barsHeight - kRadialReactionRadius) / 2;
  double _barHeight = barsHeight;
  if (rowPadding < 0) {
    rowPadding = 0;
    _barHeight = kRadialReactionRadius;
  }
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
    child: Stack(fit: StackFit.loose, children: <Widget>[

      Positioned(
        left: kRadialReactionRadius - barsWidth / 2,
        top: kRadialReactionRadius + rowPadding,
        bottom: kRadialReactionRadius + rowPadding,
        width: barsWidth,
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: List.generate(steps.length - 1, (i) =>
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kRadialReactionRadius / 2 - 2),
            height: _barHeight + 4,
            color: steps.values.elementAt(i) && steps.values.elementAt(i + 1) ? activeBarColor : inactiveBarColor,
          )
        ))
      ),
      Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(disabledColor: inactiveBarColor, unselectedWidgetColor: inactiveBarColor),
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: steps.keys.map((key) =>
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: rowPadding),
            child: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
              Checkbox(
                value: steps[key],
                onChanged: steps[key] ? (_) {} : null,
                activeColor: activeBarColor,
                materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
              ),
              Text(key),
            ])
          )
        ).toList())
      )

    ]),
  );
}
```

How it works, in short:

- `Checkbox` uses `kRadialReactionRadius` constant for its size and padding. That's how we know its exact size and now we can draw our bars in-between each checkbox row.
- Vertical bars are drawn underneath the `Column` with Checkboxes using `Stack`.
- Checkboxes default border color is overridden by `Theme` widget.

To change checkbox state - simply modify values in `steps` variable. e.g.

```dart
setState(() {
  steps[steps.keys.elementAt(/*checkbox index*/)] = true;
});
```

---

Final result:

[image: final result]

Let me know if this helped.